# Риски неактуальных данных при асинхронной реализации API

Tags: api, асинхронность

не очень глубоко погружен в материал. с АПИшками взаимодействую как тестировщик. Возник поврос, если АПИшка асинхронная, то есть ли риск получить неактулаьные данные в следующем сценарии:

1. Первый запрос, который допустим должен вывести все данные из всех возможных таблиц по каким-то условиям хитровыдуманным, но суть в том, что обработка будет долгой. Примем это как условие.
2. Второй запрос простой и короткий, допустим удалить строку или поменять поле в строке. могу чего-то не понимать в вопросе ресурсов, но допустим это обработка быстрая.

Есть ли вероятность, что из-за асинхронной реализации в респонсе на запрос №1 я получу неактуальные данные из-за более быстрой обработки запроса №2?
И если я спросил фигню, то объясните в двух словах почему? Может ссылку на статью, где написано относительно простым языком, потому что в кодинге я print("hello world")

Comment: "получу неактуальные данные из-за более быстрой обработки запроса №2"